# Donut Tutorial: The depiction of the Donut in render view

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, color

Hey :) So i was following the latest Donut Tutorial from Blender Guru for the 2.8 Version (i know, 3.0 got released, i just thought that i might better end the first one and start with 3.0 after that).

So i ran into the Problem that my donut gets depictet totally different then Gurus, and i dont figure out why. I can imagine it's some easy solution, i just don't seem to find it.

I even collated all the knods in the shading view yet they do seem to be identical. Mhm my guess would be that it is something with the render itself. But maybe someone here has a better guess.

Thank u already in advance.
Kind regards
[image]
[image]

And here how it should look.

[image]

Comment: I think "totally different" is misleading here... In both cases you have an orange torus that is bright near the middle of its height, covered in a pink icing and sprinkles. The biggest difference I can see is the size of round sprinkles, which is not based on shader nodes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey. I'm sorry for my late response. So i did sit down again to finde a solution. For clarification, i have been suprised that guru's donut is a lot more grainy in the rendered view than it has been in my shading layer. But after reading your comments i think its only due to the missing hardware power in my PC. Like you said, the rest looks quite similar. 
I'm sorry if i have wased someones time. Nonetheless thank u for your support